# React - How to import/source local images into an Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, create-react-app

I am using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-grid-gallery) library for a photo gallery on a **create-react-app** project.

Loading the images as http works fine 
ie:

```
 const IMAGES = [{
            src: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/someimage.jpg"
            ....  
         }];
```

**How can I source a local image file into an object, just like the above example?**

ie:

```
const IMAGES = [{
        src: "my local path",
        thumbnail: "my local path",   
     }];
```

I already tried:

**Gallery.js**

(ps: the path is correct and the images directory does reside inside my src directory)

```
import logo from "../images/site/logo.jpg";
export default { logo };
```

**App.js**

All the different ways I've tried so far:

```
import logo from "./Gallery";
const IMAGES = [{
        src: `${logo}`, //no dice
        src: {logo}, //no dice
        src: <logo/>, //no dice
        src: "../images/site/logo.jpg" //no dice

        ....  
     }];
```

The html console inspector says: `<img src="[object Object]" ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are exporting an object from Gallery.js, so try `logo.logo`. You could use just `logo` if you `export default logo`.

```
const IMAGES = [{
  src: logo.logo
}];
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a more elegant way to do it? Perhaps how could I do that with destructuring? Also, I can't use `export default logo` because eventually, I'll have to `export default {img1, img2, img3...}`. Thoughts?

Comment: There are two approaches that you can take. The first one is to export the object like that and then just use gallery.img1, gallery.img2 etc.. The second approach would be to use the WebpackCopyPlugin and instead store your static images in a directory that you copy to your dist/build dir. Then you just reference them as `/images/image1.png` etc. I guess it depends if you want webpack to follow dependencies and  use file-loader or not.

Answer (score 1):

logo is a object so you need to refer logo.logo

```
const IMAGES = [{
        src: `${logo.logo}`, //no dice
        src: {logo.logo}, //no dice
        ....  
     }];
```